# (Java) Using imported class constructors on methods of another class

Tags: java, import, constructor

I imported a class but I cannot use its constructor on another class' method. I can define an array as a class field though.

```
import SomeClass;

class AnotherClass
{
     SomeClass[] someClassArray = new SomeClass[2]; // works

     void someMethod()
     {
          this.someClassArray[0] = SomeClass(); // throws error: cannot find symbol
     }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: use `this.someClassArray[0] = new SomeClass();` you forgot the **new**

Comment: Cheers, that did it. I was guessing the new was probably redundant because of the array declaration so I didn't even consider it.